# Obsolete createEvenSource

Tags: c#

1. I want to create a new customevent log ( "My EeventLog") on a remote machine.

createEventSource(String,String,String) method was perferct for my need.

Unfortenatly, this method is Obsolete.

My questions is: the two other alternatives don't allow evenlog creation over a remote machine (correct me if I'm wrong).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.createeventsource.aspx

So, my easiest way to do it- is be created a new exe and run it remotely with Psexe. right?

2. Could I count eventlog entries that have some specific ID ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the ObsoleteAttribute on that type, there is an alternate way:

> This method has been deprecated. 
>   Please use
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(EventSourceCreationData
>   sourceData) instead. 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202

Use [`EventLog.CreateEventSource(EventSourceCreationData)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3.aspx) and set the [`EventSourceCreationData.MachineName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventsourcecreationdata.machinename.aspx) property to the name of the remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

the override method that takes a EventLogCreationData parameter can be used as this class has a machinename field

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zbwd3s3.aspx)